# Are lower-bounds established by reductions tight?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, complexity-theory, reduction

Reducing problem A to problem B means that problem B is at least as hard as A, if not even more so.

If I can reduce sorting to some other problem X, I know that X has a lower-bound of Omega(n log n).
Is that lower-bound guaranteed to be a tight lower-bound? I suspect that it shouldn't be, because X is only known to be at least as hard as A -- implying that it could be harder, and have a different lower-bound as a result.

I mean that in the sense that it's correct to say that because insertion sort has a worst-case tight upper-bound of O(n^2), it's also correct to say it has a worst-case running time of O(n^3). It's correct, but not of much practical value -- because we're interested in tight bounds 99% of the time.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce sorting to some other problem"? You mean like sub-algorithms in certain sorting algorithms, e.g. *partition* in quicksort, *merge* in mergesort, and *heapify* in heapsort?

Comment: This may be also be of interest to Computer Science Stack Exchange: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right, the bound does not need to be tight.

For instance, consider a simple example: finding the smallest integer in an array of `n` integers. There is an `O(1)` space and `O(n)` time algorithm to solve this problem every time. However, this problem reduces to the problem of sorting an array of integers via a reduction in `O(1)` both ways:

1. Transforming `MININT` input to `SORTINT` input: use `MININT`'s input directly for `SORTINT`.
2. Transforming `SORTINT` output to `MININT` output: return the first element of the sorted array (assuming elements are sorted in ascending order).

Sorting certainly does have a lower bound of Omega(n) on worst-case inputs. This is not a tight bound; Omega(n lg n) is tighter for `SORTINT`. But the reduction of `MININT` to `SORTINT`, by itself, does not tell us that.